# How to use tailwind class so when group is active set the after to opacity-100 and scale-100

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, next.js13, nextui

```
<Link
    href={{
        query: createQueryString("tags", tag.id.toString())
    }}
    key={tag.id}
    replace={true}
    className="group relative inline-flex -m-2 p-2"
>
    <div className="absolute inset-0 z-10"></div>
    <Checkbox
        isSelected={tagsQuery?.includes(tag.id.toString())}
        value={tag.id.toString()}
        radius={"sm"}
        className={"text-body font-body"}
        classNames={{
            icon: "group-active:opacity-100 after:group-active:opacity-100 after:group-active:scale-100"
        }}
        style={{position: "relative", backgroundColor: "transparent"}}
    />
</Link>
```

I try to put different order like group-active:after but it's not work.
I hope I can find a way to pull this problem off.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve the desired effect is by using JavaScript to manually toggle classes. In your component, you can manage the active state with the useState hook and update it based on user interactions, like mouse enter and leave events.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Link
      href={{
        query: createQueryString("tags", tag.id.toString())
      }}
      key={tag.id}
      replace={true}
      className="group relative inline-flex -m-2 p-2"
      onMouseEnter={() => setIsActive(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setIsActive(false)}
    >
      <div className="absolute inset-0 z-10"></div>
      <Checkbox
        isSelected={tagsQuery?.includes(tag.id.toString())}
        value={tag.id.toString()}
        radius={"sm"}
        className={`text-body font-body ${
          isActive ? "opacity-100 scale-100" : ""
        }`}
        style={{ position: "relative", backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
      />
    </Link>
  );
};
```